# I want to change the font of text

Tags: c#, xaml

Why not working to change the font in this text?

```
 <TextBlock FontFamily="./#Bowhouse-Black" FontSize="25">asdada</TextBlock>
```

I attached a picture to understand what I did

http://i59.tinypic.com/iqyfmg.png

Comment: Is the Bowhouse-Black font in the same location as the current XAML file?

Comment: Where Bowhouse-Black is installed/copied ? That's seems to be a problem with the path ...

Comment: Your Properties for the Bowhouse_black.oft file have the Copy to Output Directory property set to 'Do not copy'.  Try 'Copy if newer'.  Then you can find out where it is located in the output folders and set the path accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write

```
FontFamily="./#Bowhouse-Black"
```

according to MSDN :

> notice that the relative URI value uses the "./" notation, which means
>   "in the current folder" of the base URI value.

The file `Bowhouse_black.oft` must be present to current directory, so it must be copied with exe.

Change `Copy To Output Directory` option for this file to `Copy if newer` or `Copy always`